# How to properly codesign macOS Screensaver?

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, screensaver

I'm trying to codesign my macOS screensaver project to get rid of the "unidentified developer" warning message. Both [Apple's documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev033e997ca) and [this person on Apple's forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15483) say that you should use the "Developer ID Application" signing certificate to do it. But that doesn't appear to work for me.

When I follow [Apple's instructions on how to test for proper signatures](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev1cc22a95c) the response I get is as follows:

```
Screensaver.saver: rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)
```

My signing settings look like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what else I should try at this point. Mostly I'm worried about the rumor future mac apps will have to be signed/notarized and what does that means for screensavers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are additional notarization notes:

You can’t notarize the .saver directly, but you can in a round-about-way notarize a ZIP file, which is how I distribute my screen saver.  Here are the steps I use for my simple saver, your mileage will undoubtably vary:

1. /usr/bin/codesign -f -o runtime --timestamp --sign “insert Developer
   ID Installer certificate identifier here” XYZZY.saver
2. compress the code signed .saver e.g. XYZZY.saver.zip
3. /usr/bin/xcrun altool --verbose --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id “insert identifier here" -u “xyzzy@plugh.com" -p “insert app-specific PW for your Apple    ID here" -t osx -f XYZZY.saver.zip
4. Aside: store the App-specific  password in your keychain and
   reference it from the command line like this:

   - /usr/bin/xcrun altool
     --store-password-in-keychain-item
     "AC_PASSWORD" -u xyzzy@plugh.com -p “insert App-specific PW from Apple here”
5. wait for notarization, check status like this:

   - /usr/bin/xcrun altool  --notarization-history 0 -u “xyzzy@plugh.com"
     -p "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD”
6. While you can notarize a ZIP archive, you can’t staple the
   notarization ticket to it directly. Instead, run  stapler against
   each individual item that you originally added to the archive. Then
   create a new ZIP file containing the stapled items for distribution.

   - /usr/bin/xcrun stapler staple  XYZZY.saver
   - Re-zip the saver and
     distribute

Comment: I can't understand this line:  Instead, run stapler against each individual item that you originally added to the archive

Comment: My ZIP file contains a single item, the saver module XYZZY.saver, thus I run the stapler command once: /usr/bin/xcrun stapler staple XYZZY.saver.  If you have more than one item in the archive then run the stapler command for every item, then recreate the archive.

Comment: OK I will try that, so after level #5 I should unzip my XYZZY.saver.zip & staple it with that command line & zip it again!, then how to distribute it?, could you guide me a little for distribution?

Comment: When I check the notarizations, I get Package Invalid!

Comment: I did NOT unzip the archive.  Simply staple each *original* item that was included in the zip archive.  Then re-create the archive, overwriting what you notarized.  At least that is what I did.  The saver module, even though it's really a folder (package), counts as a single "file".  Then "distribute" the notarized saver by simply giving it to folks, say, by storing on a server and advertising its URL.

Comment: Can confirm that this seems to work. I followed that advice, and tested on a fresh VM with brand new install of macOS Catalina. The screensaver installed without as much as a prompt. Thanks @pabugeater for detailed on point instructions.

Comment: Thanks for this! Much better than my package solution. With noting for others: I had to use a "Developer ID Application" certificate, not the "Developer ID Installer" certificate.

Comment: This post was incredibly helpful for me. You can see an example of it here using the new `xcrun notarytool` command https://github.com/TehNrd/Apple-Logo-Screensaver/blob/main/buildsign.sh

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone else stumbles in here...

For now I've realized that a good way around this is to create an installer package and then sign that [following Apple's instructions](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deve51ce7c3d).

I ended up using some free software called [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create the installer. After building the installer, I copied it to another folder and used the following command to sign it.

`/usr/bin/productsign --sign "<Name of Developer ID Installer Cert in Keychain>" source.pkg destination-signed.pkg`

Hope this helps someone out there. As far as I can tell this gets around the unidentified developer warning.